# In OOP, Private membes are private for who?

Tags: java, c++, oop

In OOP why need to put something `Private` , for example. I know that any private member can not be accessed but with the same class objects. But why I need to do that while I am the only coder of my project. The same question extends to `Protected`, protected from who!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`private` and `protected` are not there to prevent other coders from accessing the internals of a class, but (also) to prevent *yourself* from creating a program without clearly defined interfaces.

If every class in your project can modify every other class, you're not only prone to introduce bugs because of the huge state space, but also preventing yourself from:

- Changing the implementation (while keeping the interface the same) of any class.
- Ever introducing anyone not familiar with all the internals of all the classes to the project. Unless you have a perfect memory and can recite every line of code you've ever written, that includes future you.
- Mocking up objects for unit testing
- Interacting with other versions of your program/library. Suppose you do change internals of one class, and you manage to track down every reference to that internal property in your project. Even then, you may need to interface with the old version of your program again. This becomes especially hard if used properties instead of getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 7):

Access modifiers achieve two different things:

1. They limit the amount of code that can cause side effects, making it easier to establish invariants.
2. They protect clients of the class from changes to the internal representation.

For small projects, these advantages might not be immediately visible, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

Protected from your future self, who could otherwise accidentally forget what parts of an object are a detail that should be decoupled from the rest of the system, and which parts are a solid interface that can be relied on by the rest of the system.

Answer (score 5):

the language tries to force you, to write "good" code. "good" means that the code is structured, clean and not susceptible to error. so you have to declare types, private members and so on. if you don't want that, you could use a language thats lesser in this aspects, like python. but this means, that your program could (could!) be more insecure or if it gets very big, easy to misunderstand. it's the same as with comments. you haven't to write them. especially when you are the only programmer. but it's a good style and you will be very thankfull for that if you read your program again, in a half year.

Answer (score 4):

You mark the members of a class `private` that must not be accessed from outside the class. E.g., you use it to hide implementation details, so you can change the implementation without affecting other code *using* your class. Hiding implementation details is one of the key aspects of OOP (encapsulation). If you create a `Car` class, and then you write a lot of code that uses the `Car` class, and you suddenly realize that your implementation performs very poorly and you need to refactor it, if all of the `Car` implementation details are private to the `Car` class, you *know* that none of the code using `Car` accesses those things and you can change them at will. If you didn't mark them `private`, you might have used some of them in that other code, which would then break.

Similarly, `protected` (in Java, anyway) is for the same purpose but allows classes *derived* from your class to access those members. This is fairly weak protection, because of course it means that you can't change the implementation details of the base class without affecting derived classes.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it this way: The protection level defines what you can change later without care for any other piece of code besides this class (private), without care for any other piece of code besides this class and every class inheriting from this class (protected) and without care for any other piece of code besides every piece of code using this class (public).

Answer (score 1):

`private` or `protected` come from encapsulation concept. and it comes from data hiding concept. I believe this intoduction is clear and useful at least for me :

> Encapsulation is the process of combining data and functions into a
>   single unit called class. Using the method of encapsulation, the
>   programmer cannot directly access the data. Data is only accessible
>   through the functions existing inside the class. Data encapsulation
>   led to the important concept of data hiding. Data hiding is the
>   implementation details of a class that are hidden from the user. The
>   concept of restricted access led programmers to write specialized
>   functions or methods for performing the operations on hidden members
>   of the class. Attention must be paid to ensure that the class is
>   designed properly.  ([Sripriya Rajagopalan](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-plus-plus/encapsulation--an-introduction.html))

*Note: Answers are well, and this answer is to complete them*

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question about private/protected.

Comment: I saw the note the first time. You haven't answered the question about `private`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a member (variable or method) of a class as private, you won't be able to use it from outside, using another class, using the dot operator. Protected helps you to protect the member variable or method from being inherited.